# Use the value of a variable for an enum value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, groovy, enums, aws-sdk

Im using the AWS api in my groovy script:

```
new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder ()
            .withRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1)
            .build()
```

I want to be able to pass in the region to the script as a user argument but Regions is an enum. How can I pass the region (like "SA_EAST_1" or "CN_NORTH_1") as a string? I could have my own map to convert the string values to the enum values but that seems really dumb.

Comment: pass the string and use Regions.valueof(...)

Comment: what would that look like? Im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // convert the enum value to a string using name
    String name = Region.SA_EAST_1.name();
    // convert the string to a enum value
    Region value = Region.valueOf(name);
```